# DB2 ZOS String Comparison Problem

Tags: c#, db2, zos

I am comparing some CHAR data in a where clause in my sql like this,

where PRI_CODE < PriCode

The problem I am having is when the CHAR values are of different lengths.
So if PRI_CODE = '0800' and PriCode = '20'  it is returning true instead of false.

It looks like it is comparing it like this

```
'08' < '20'
```

instead of like

```
'0800' < '20'
```

Does a CHAR comparison start from the Left until one or the other values end?

If so how do I fix this?

My values can have letters in it so convering to numeric is not an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not comparing '08' with '20', it is, as you expect, comparing '0800' with '20'.

What you don't seem to expect, however, is that '0800' (the string) is *indeed* less than '20' (the string).

If converting it to numerics for a numeric comparison is out of the question, you could use the following DB2 function:

```
right ('0000000000'||val,10)
```

which will give you `val` padded on the left with zeroes to a size of 10 (ideal for a `CHAR(10)`, for example). That will at least guarantee that the fields are the same size and the comparison will work for your particular case. But I urge you to rethink how you're doing things: per-row functions rarely scale well, performance-wise.

If you're using z/OS, you should have a few DBAs just lying around on the computer room floor waiting for work - you can probably ask one of them for advice more tailored to your specific application :-)

One thing that comes to mind in the use of an insert/update trigger and secondary column `PRI_CODE_PADDED` to hold the `PRI_CODE` column fully padded out (using the same method as above). Then make sure your `PriCode` variable is similarly formatted before executing the `select ... where PR_CODE_PADDED < PriCode`.

Incurring that cost at insert/update time will amortise it over all the selects you're likely to do (which, because they're no longer using per-row functions, will be blindingly fast), giving you better overall performance (assuming your database isn't one of those incredibly rare beasts that are written more than read, of course).

Comment: +1 for the crack about having "a few DBAs lying around on the computer room floor waiting for work"